# OpenID Connect: Get claims for a group of users

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm implementing my own OpenID Connect provider using Identity Server 4.
I understand, that once issued an access token, clients can use it to obtain claims about the end-user from the userinfo endpoint. Which works great, by the way.

However there are certain use cases where it might be necessary to obtain claims about other users in the system. Think about a user who is head of a department. Clients might want to get email addresses of other users in this department on behalf of this user to notify them about something.

**My question is**: Is such functionality covered by OpenID Connect or is there a feature in Identity Server 4 to help with this?

I see that I could implement this myself by exposing part of my identity service as just another api protected by the identity server itself. For my use case it would probably be enough to flag certain claims as public for other users, so they can be accessed like any other resource. However there might be some security issues I might be overlooking. Also I would be interested if there was a non-proprietary way to do it, so it could be used by arbitrary clients, and show up in the discovery document.

Any input on this topic would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't treat other user's data as claims. A claim is normally treated as asserting something about the authenticated user, so I'd be inclined to use the claims about the authenticated user (e.g. 'head of department X') to decide whether they are authorised to access requested data (e.g. email addresses of everyone in department X). Having said all this, I don't know if this is functionality covered by OIC, or Identity Server, so am just providing input as requested.